# Need to bypass asynchronous nature of ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

i know Extjs have asynchronous behaviour but still i need a way to print the console.log('value of x'+x); as "value of x 1"

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var x=0;
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm', 'Are you sure you want to do that?', showResult );

    function showResult(btn){

            Ext.Msg.show({
                   title: 'number',
                   msg: 'Please enter your number:',
                   width: 300,
                   buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
                   multiline: true,
                   fn: saveNumber,
                   icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
                });
        function saveNumber(){
            x=1;
        }


    }
    console.log('value of x'+x); //want this value to be 1 without changing the line of this statement
});
```

Comment: You can not do it. That is not how JavaScript works.

Comment: just consider a scenario if i provide some prompt to user in Ext.Msg,show and take the user input in that.


and then need to send the same user input to ajax call.......

is that possible?

above question is the simpler version of this question.>>

Comment: There is no wait/sleep in JavaScript, that is why there is a callback. The code needs to be dealt with in the callback.

Comment: i am new to javascript so could you please help me out by applying the callback to above program.

Comment: That is what  `saveNumber` is.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, you would have to use a function to do your callback tasks.
An idea is:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
        title:'Number?',
        message: 'Please enter your number: ',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OKCANCEL,
        multiline: true,
        icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
        fn: function(btn,txt) {
            if(btn==='ok') {
                var number = parseInt(txt,10);
                console.log('Your number is: ' + number);
            }
        }
    });
```

or even better:

```
Ext.Msg.prompt('Number?', 'Please enter your number: ', function(btn,txt){  
        if(btn==='ok') {
            var number = parseInt(txt,10);
            console.log(number);
        }
    });
```